# LINQ query adding orderby makes Skip and Take not work Linqpad

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to use Skip and Take for my paging, but I also want to use orderby

Without the Skip and Take,  with LinqPad I can do the following and this works with orderby

```
var query = from m in Orders
            orderby m.ID descending
            select m;
query.Dump();
```

However, if I keep the orderby in, then this fails

```
query = query.Skip(1 + 10).Take(10);
query.Dump();
```

I remove the orderby and it works,  but I want the orderby ....

```
var query = from m in Orders
    select m;   
query = query.Skip(1 + 10).Take(10);            
query.Dump();
```

Comment: What do you mean by *it fails*?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Error occurs, because you use `var` and compiler infer `query` type as `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` after your first query, and you're trying to assign `IEnumerable<T>` to it with `Skip`/`Take` calls:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Order>`' to
>   '`System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<Order>`'. An explicit conversion exists
>   (are you missing a cast?)

If you type `query` as `IEnumerable<T>` at the beginning everything will work just fine

```
IEnumerable<Order> query = from m in Orders
                           orderby m.ID descending
                           select m;

query = query.Skip(10).Take(10);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I was even doing  query = query. ...   I must prefer this style    var query = (from m in Orders
            orderby m.ID ascending
            select m).Skip(1 + 10).Take(10); 
   
 query.Dump();

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer is correct, however If you are not binding to a model with of Type Order, then this would work

MarcinJuraszek is correct.

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Order>' to 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<Order>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

You will get that error the way you are doing it

**HOWEVER to NOT have to use `IEnumerable<Order>`**  ...

```
var query = (from m in Orders
        orderby m.ID descending
        select m).Skip(10).Take(10);
query.Dump();
```

I had the same issue in **LINQPAD** when I knew that I wanted to skip over the first record

So for me :

```
 var comments = (from c in ESO_tblComments
                         .Where(d => d.TblTipsId == 10312)   
                orderby c.Id ascending
                select c).Skip(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

for more. if you use it or not you can sort your query without ascending or descending style. you can use below code.

```
 var comments = (from c in ESO_tblComments
                     .Where(d => d.TblTipsId == 10312)
            select c).OrderBy(xx=>1==1).Skip(1);
```