# Why does the Take method ignore ordering methods in C# Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-order-by, take

I have a code snippet like this:

```
IReadOnlyList<ResultDTO> res = Repository.GetAll()
.Skip(input.SkipCount)
.Join(UserManager.Users, d=>d.CreatorUserId, c=> c.Id,
   (d, c)=>d.MapToDto(c.UserName)
)
.OrderBy(x=>x.VerifiedByAdmin)
.ThenByDescending(x=>x.CreationTime)
.Take(input.MaxResultCount)
.ToList();
```

My expected result is all records that are not verified first and then verified records.
this code works properly when I remove the ***.Take(input.MaxResultCount)*** line but when this line is uncommented the result is not ordered according to my expectation.
I have changed the order of my code but re result was the same.
this code is written by Aspnet boilerplate.
My code does not throw any exception also my return the result into an **IReadOnlyList** and not a var variable.
Maybe this can be helpful if I say my database is SQLite.

Comment: Could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270288/linq-query-adding-orderby-makes-skip-and-take-not-work-linqpad?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ query adding orderby makes Skip and Take not work Linqpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270288/linq-query-adding-orderby-makes-skip-and-take-not-work-linqpad)

Comment: To avoid side effects, you should place `Skip` exactly before `Take`

Comment: I put that exactly there but the result still is unordered

Comment: Did you intentionally put the `Skip` *before* the order by?

Comment: yes, I put these two functions everywhere I could. I put them before orderby, after orderby , put them in any order you can think. but no change in result.

Comment: MoreLINQ has special methods: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#partialsort

Comment: What's your expected output though? If you have 5 records that are verified by admin and 5 that are not, and you orderby that bool, then by date, then skip 2 and take 4 you should have 3 that are not verified and 1 that is (and the earliest 2 not verified and latest 4 that are verified are lost)

Comment: yes, I expect such a result but it actually returns all verified records first.

Comment: would it be possible for you to post examplary input, so that we can copy paste your code and recreate this problem?

Comment: I would expect it to return all verified records first, so it's working how I expect.

Comment: I don't see how the Take() call (in its posted position) is affecting the sort order, but you absolutely want the Skip() call directly before the Take() (both of which absolutely must occur after the sort calls).